# Segmentation fault when reading avi from file OpenCV

Tags: opencv, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read and show avi from file using OpenCV and following code:

```
 #include <cv.h>
 #include <highgui.h>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  VideoCapture cap("myvideo.avi");

  if (!cap.isOpened()){
    cout << "!!! Failed to open file: " << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  Mat frame;

  while(1){
    if (!cap.read(frame))             
        break;

    imshow("window",frame);

    char key = cvWaitKey(10);
    if (key == 27) // ESC
        break;
  }

  return 0;
 }
```

And I'm getting segmentation fault when I am trying to read next frame.
If I try to capture video from web cam by modifying line VideoCapture cap("myvideo.avi") to VideoCapture cap(0) everything works well.
I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Any idea why I am getting segmentation fault when reading from file?

Comment: Yes, VLC player has no problem whit it.

Comment: I am not sure and maybe totaly wrong, but could my problem has something in common with missing ffmpeg package on Ubuntu 14.04? As suggested here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04] I am using avconv instead.